# emmeans: interaction contrast with continuous variable - same se, t- and p-values?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, contrasts, lsmeans

I am analysing my own data with a linear mixed model and estimated marginal means and have made a strange observation. I have run an experimental study with three treatment groups, measuring a dependent variable at three points. I also measured a continuous covariate. The structure of the data is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(afex)
library(emmeans)

df <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:3, 100), 
  treatment = rep(1:3, 100), 
  t1 = runif(300, min = 1, max = 4), 
  t2 = runif(300, min = 1, max = 4), 
  t3 = runif(300, min = 1, max = 4), 
  cov = runif(300, min = 1, max = 4)
)
str(df)
```

I restructured the data..

```
df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(t1, t2, t3), 
               values_to = "y", 
               names_to = "time")
```

and computed the lmm using the afex package.

```
lmm <- mixed(y ~ time*treatment*cov + (1|id), df_long)
```

There is a significant interaction between time and covariate in my data. So I want to compare the contrasts between measuring points depending on the covariate. I use certain values (-sd, m, +sd) for the covariate

```
lsmeans(lmm, ~time*cov,at = list(cov = c(1, 2, 3))) %>% 
contrast(interaction = "pairwise", adjust = "bonferroni")

 time_pairwise cov_pairwise estimate     SE  df t.ratio p.value
 t1 - t2       1 - 2         -0.1555 0.0791 887  -1.967  0.4454
 t1 - t3       1 - 2         -0.1251 0.0791 887  -1.582  1.0000
 t2 - t3       1 - 2          0.0304 0.0791 887   0.385  1.0000
 t1 - t2       1 - 3         -0.3110 0.1581 887  -1.967  0.4454
 t1 - t3       1 - 3         -0.2501 0.1581 887  -1.582  1.0000
 t2 - t3       1 - 3          0.0609 0.1581 887   0.385  1.0000
 t1 - t2       2 - 3         -0.1555 0.0791 887  -1.967  0.4454
 t1 - t3       2 - 3         -0.1251 0.0791 887  -1.582  1.0000
 t2 - t3       2 - 3          0.0304 0.0791 887   0.385  1.0000

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 9 tests
```

In the output, I see that the contrasts between the values of the covariates all have the same standard error, the same t-values and the same p-values. What is the reason for this?

**EDIT:**
When I plot my data, I can clearly see that the slope is different depending on the covariate. However, I still get the following output:

```
lsmeans(lmm,~time*cov, at = list(cov = c(-0.88, 0, 0.88))) %>% contrast(interaction = "pairwise", adjust = "bonferroni")

 time_pairwise cov_pairwise estimate     SE  df t.ratio p.value
 MZP2 - MZP1   (-0.88) - 0      -0.161 0.0755 201  -2.136  0.1016
 MZP2 - MZP1   (-0.88) - 0.88   -0.323 0.1510 201  -2.136  0.1016
 MZP2 - MZP1   0 - 0.88         -0.161 0.0755 201  -2.136  0.1016

Results are averaged over the levels of: treatment
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 3 tests
```

Depending on the covariate, is there another way to analyse the contrasts between the measurement points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly in order because `cov` is a continuous variable and so its effects are slopes. There is a different slope for each `time`, but those three slopes are the same regardless of the value of `cov`.

Comment: When I plot my data, I can clearly see that the slope is different depending on the covariate. But this is not reflected in the output. I have added more information to my post.

Comment: But with your model, for a given `tj`, the slope at `cov=1` is the same as it is at `cov2` and `cov3`. In other words, your model fits linear trends for `cov`. If you don't think that's right, then you need a different model. Remember, `emmeans()` doesn't analyze your data, it analyzes your model.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will check my model again